# AWS Codebuild + S3 Bucket as Source - How to run multiple concurrent builds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I currently use Bamboo as CI/CD tool, it works great, we can build multiple branches of a Gitlab repository concurrently, I just have to add a single Build Configuration and all branches under Gitlab repository use this configuration to do builds.

I am testing AWS Codebuild, Since there is no native support for Gitlab in AWS Codebuild, so I am zipping my Gitlab respository/branch and uploading it to S3 bucket and Using this very bucket as Source in AWS CodeBuild. Build works great. The question I have is:

I have 5 developers working on a single project(Repository) in Gitlab and everyone has their own separate branches, their branches build fine in bamboo and separately, but how can I achieve it in CodeBuild? Every-time there is code push in Gitlab, my configured webhooks zip it and upload it to S3 bucket and CodePipeline triggers the build, In this way I have one build running at a time, how can i configure AWS Codebuild to run multiple concurrent builds in this scenario?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Still looking for any reply/suggestion on this issue